# How to ask Mathematica to simplify an expression in terms of a particular variable?

Tags: simplifying-expressions

With the following matrix where there are relations between different variables `a`,`b`,`c`,`d`, how can I instruct Mathematica to yield the answer only in terms of variables `a` and `X`

```
    d/(2 b) == X; (b + c)/(2b) == X; (e - b)/(2b) == X;

mat = FullSimplify[{{a - I ((b + c)/2), d}, {d, a - I ((e - b)/2)}}]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
```

Since there are only three equations for the relations, you can only eliminate three variables. In addition to `a` and `X`, `e` will also remain.

```
repl = Solve[{d/(2 b) == X, (b + c)/(2 b) == X, (e - b)/(2 b) == X},
   {b, c, d}][[1]]

(* {b -> e/(1 + 2 X), c -> (e (-1 + 2 X))/(1 + 2 X), d -> (2 e X)/(1 + 2 X)} *)

mat = {{a - I ((b + c)/2), d}, {d, a - I ((e - b)/2)}} /. repl // Simplify

(* {{(a + 2 a X - I e X)/(1 + 2 X), (2 e X)/(1 + 2 X)}, {(2 e X)/(1 + 2 X), 
  (a + 2 a X - I e X)/(1 + 2 X)}} *)
```